# Efficient technique for sending text messages to UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF Windows app.  The viewmodel calls a method in the format of Model.TrySomething(), which returns a boolean if anything in TrySomething logically fails.  If false is returned, the UI can throw a message back to the user.

What is the best way to bubble this message up from the model?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it on our projects. Works fine:

```
// your event args might include more properties
public class ShowMessageBoxEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

// example of your model base
public class MyModelBase
{
    public event EventHandler<ShowMessageBoxEventArgs> ShowMessageBox;
    protected void RaiseShowMessageBox(string title, string text)
    {
        if (ShowMessageBox == null)
            return;
        var _Args = new ShowMessageBoxEventArgs
        {
            Text = text,
            Title = title
        };
        ShowMessageBox(this, _Args);
    }
}

// for this sample, this is your view model
public class MyModel : MyModelBase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // TODO: Do Something
        base.RaiseShowMessageBox("DoSomething", "Complete!");
    }
}

// this is your window or in app.xaml.cs (where we do it)
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyModel m_MyModel = new MyModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = m_MyModel;
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    bool m_Loaded = false; // only once
    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_Loaded)
            return;
        m_Loaded = true;

        // allow model to show messagebox
        m_MyModel.ShowMessageBox += (s, arg) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(arg.Text, arg.Title);
        };
    }
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: What is the variable 'Loaded'?

Comment: this.Loaded is the standard WPF Window event. This event occurs every time the Window is added to or refreshed in the Visual Tree. As a result, m_Loaded simply prevents multiple handlings. This is especially important for the Loaded handler in UserControls.

Answer (score 0):

If the message which you want to display is a modal dialog, you can write a service (lets name it MessageDialogService) which is injected in your viewmodel and then call a MessageDialogService.Show() method. This method creates a new WPF window and shows the message.

This service can then be used in any of your ViewModels to show messages.